# useSelector does not return the current value from the Redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

React beginner here.

I am updating the `Redux` store with a `result` value which is either true or false.

I want to later use that value in another component. I dispatch the value with a function wrapped with `useEffect`, the `result` value being in the dependency array. (Result is being initialised as false in the local state.)

```
export const Sudoku = () => {

const dispatch = useDispatch()

const [result, setResult] = useState(false)


const puzzle = useSelector(store => store.sudoku.easySudoku)
const solution = useSelector(store => store.sudoku.easySudokuSolution)
const elapsedSeconds = useSelector(store => store.sudoku.time)
const accessToken = useSelector(store => store.user.login.accessToken)
const username = useSelector(store => store.user.login.username)

//compare the two arrays:
const isCorrect = () => {

for (let i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {

  for (let j = 0; j < solution[i].length; j++) {

    if (solution[i][j] !== Number(puzzle[i][j])) {

      return false

    }
  }
}
return true
}

const postToLeaderboard = () => {
fetch(LEADERBOARD_URL, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, time: elapsedSeconds }),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
})
  .then((response) => {

    console.log(response.json())
    if (!response.ok) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      throw "Sorry, could not post to leaderboard";
    }
    else console.log("response was ok!")
    // return response.json();
  })
}

const dispatchResult = () => {
dispatch(sudoku.actions.updateResult({ result }))
}

useEffect(() => {

dispatchResult()
// eslint-disable-next-line
}, [result])

const evaluateGame = () => {

if (isCorrect()) {
  if (elapsedSeconds > 30) {

    postToLeaderboard()
    setResult(true)
    console.log("Hej, this is true!")


  } else {
    console.log("No time, this is true!")
    setResult(true)

  }

} else {
  console.log("This is false!")
  setResult(false)
}
}


if (accessToken) {

return (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Timer />
    <Grid />
    {/* <Link to={`/result`}> */}
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      type="submit"
      onClick={evaluateGame}>
      Check solution!
    </Button>
    {/* </Link> */}
  </>
)
} else {
  return <LoginHere text={"Want to play sudoku?"} />
}
}
```

The `result` value is being changed when I click on a button and trigger a function that does some evaluation.

The button is wrapped with `<Link>` to lead to the page where I want to go next and use the updated `result` value from the store (i.e. the result of the function triggered by the button click).

I noticed the `Redux` store is updated with the correct value when I do not use the `<Link>`, however, when I DO use it & I end up on the desired page, the value retrieved from the store is not correct, ebenthough is see in the console, the line "No time, this is true!" is being printed out meaning the `result` was set to true just a bit before.

Would really appreciate help on that. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the result state at all? Why not just call `dispatch(updateResult(  ))` inside the evaluateGame() function? It is very odd to setState and then useEffect to dispatch the state change. As a general rule, state should live in one and only one place. It appears that you have it here both in component state, and in redux state.

Comment: If you click on the `Link` you are going to immediately navigate away from the page with this component.  I wouldn't be surprised if you're seeing the warning "can't perform a state update on an unmounted component".